# html and js not working the same with flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

i have a folder which contains server.py a templates folder with index.html and a js folder with script.js
server.py:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
import random

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sparkle Trail and Dust Cursor</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Sparkle Trail and Dust Cursor</h1>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/script.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js can be found here: https://codepen.io/sarahwfox/pen/pNrYGb its too long probably but yeah im trying to have this effect but it either doesnt show anything or it shows the trail following the cursor but not the + sparkles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's python/flask related, as I was having the same issue as you describe with basic html page and inline css and javascript. It's also not the javascript. It's a sneaky styling issue.

Your page will not take up any vertical space by default. You need to set the style property `height: 100vh` in the body of your html page either inline (`<body style="height: 100vh">`) or with css (`body { height: 100vh; }`).

This is what's stopping your animation, and it's also why this is a confusing bug to sort out. You could copy codepen exactly, including the css, but the site still includes *some* hidden formatting just to save space for the rendered page, and in this case it made all the difference.

Comment: AVOID COMMENTS LIKE THANKS?? dont caree THANK YOU SO MUCH i didnt think the css file would make that bigga difference thank you thank you thank youuuu